# JBOSS JNDI Stateless bean lookup String

Tags: jboss, ejb, jndi, lookup

Deploying an EJB app with Eclipse tools on JBOSS 7.1
what's the format of the look up string to use.

I took a look at the docs,but I'm getting really confused

```
context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);
```

Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

When the ejb is deployed (e.g. when the ejb is deployed to the server or the server is restarted) you should see something like this in the output:

```
2015 Jun 07, 18:07:24.352 (MSC service thread 1-4) INFO  - (AbstractDeploymentUnitService.java:66) start - JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "_ExampleEjbProject.war"
2015 Jun 07, 18:07:24.463 (MSC service thread 1-4) INFO  - (EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:182) setupJNDIBindings - JNDI bindings for session bean named SayHelloEjb in deployment unit deployment "_ExampleEjbProject.war" are as follows:

    java:global/_ExampleEjbProject/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.local.SayHelloLocal
    java:app/_ExampleEjbProject/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.local.SayHelloLocal
    java:module/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.local.SayHelloLocal
    java:global/_ExampleEjbProject/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.remote.SayHelloRemote
    java:app/_ExampleEjbProject/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.remote.SayHelloRemote
    java:module/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.remote.SayHelloRemote
    java:jboss/exported/_ExampleEjbProject/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.remote.SayHelloRemote
```

This is the list of strings that can be used in different contexts for the jndi lookup string.  In this case my project name is _ExampleEjbProject, there is no submodule, The bean class (the implementation) is annotated with this "@Stateless(name = "SayHelloEjb")" to give the ejb name, and the local and remote interfaces are "org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.local.SayHelloLocal" and "org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.remote.SayHelloLocal" respectively. The lookup strings follow the pattern:

```
<project_name>/<submodule>/<EJB_name>!<interface_name>.
```

From a standalone application I am able to connect using this string:

```
/_ExampleEjbProject/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.remote.SayHelloRemote
```

Like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
        String providerURL = "remote://localhost:7447";
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.class.getName());
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerURL);
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, MY_UID);
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, MY_PWD);
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        testLookup(context, "/_ExampleEjbProject/SayHelloEjb!org.yaorma.examples.ejb.server.remote.SayHelloRemote");
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

    private static void testLookup(InitialContext context, String lookupString) throws Exception {
        Object obj = context.lookup(lookupString);
        SayHelloRemote sayHelloRemote = (SayHelloRemote) obj;
        String msg = sayHelloRemote.sayHello("John");
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
```